# spring cloud config server unable to connect to private git repository (not authorized)

Tags: spring-boot, github, spring-cloud-config, jgit, spring-cloud-config-server

I want to use private git repository with my config server. Here is my application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=PhotoAppApiConfigServer
server.port=8012
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/nasrouu/PhotoAppConfiguration.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=myusername
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=mypassword

spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=busrefresh

spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
```

I get the following error:

```
Error occured cloning to base directory

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException:
https://github.com/nasrouu/PhotoAppConfiguration.git: not authorized
```

application.properties for my private github repositorie

```
gateway.ip=192.168.2.82
token.expiration_time=864000000
token.secret=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9eyJpZCI6IjVjOWYzYW
I2NzY2Mjg2NDYyNDY0YTczNCIsIm5hbWUiOiJSYW5keSIsImF2YXRhciI6I
i8vd3d3LmdyYXZhdGFyLmNvbS9hdmF0YXIvMTNhN2MyYzdkOGVk 
NTNkMDc2MzRkOGNlZWVkZjM0NTEcz0yMDAmcj1wZyZkPW1tIiwi
aWF0IjoxNTU0NTIxNjk1LCJleHAiOjE1NTQ1MjUyOTV9SxRurShXSSI3SE11z6nme9EoaD2
9TDBFr8Qwngkg
login.url.path=/users/login
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: You need to generate a token. GitHub doesn’t permit operation with username and password anymore. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66320935/spring-cloud-config-server-git-not-authorized)

Answer (score 1):

you must create a personal access token
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

then you copy the generated token as del key into the config file aplicación.propiedades.
For example:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/joselizagaravito/RepositoryDemo
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=myusername
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=ghp_8ArBnIhaRUD4omMscbwOMydb4445556663
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using github and the new [fine grained access token](https://github.com/settings/personal-access-tokens/new) generated from github. In that case the username and password both must be set to the same token generated.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-service
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/UserName/PrivateRepo
          username: github_fine_access_token_xxxx
          password: github_fine_access_token_xxxx
```